# WPF TextBlock doesn't wrap

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a datatemplate that has a Border as root and a grid as child of the Border. I subdivided the grid into cells and placed a textblock in one of the cells. But oddly, this textblock does not wrap its content.

The TextBlock as shown in the below xaml code is placed in a cell whose width is dynamic but it doesn't wrap.

Can someone tell me what is the problem with my xaml code please?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dtConversation" DataType="{x:Type model:Conversation}">
        <Border Padding="10 5"
                Name="brd"
                Height="70"
                Background="Transparent">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Height="40"
                            Width="40"
                            CornerRadius="20"
                            Background="#373A3E"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Margin="0 5 5 5"
                            Padding="3"
                            >
                    <Path Stretch="Uniform"
                              Fill="#fff"
                              Width="24"
                              Height="24"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Data="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource typeToIconConverter}}"
                              />
                </Border>

                <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                      Background="Yellow">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DestinataireName}"
                                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                   FontSize="16" 
                                   Margin="0 0 10 0"
                               Name="txtDestinataire"/>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastMessage.Date, Converter={StaticResource shortDateConverter}}"
                                   Foreground="#777"
                                   FontSize="11"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Name="txtDate"
                                   />
                    </Grid>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                               Foreground="#999"
                               Text="{Binding LastMessage.Content}" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               MaxHeight="40"
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                               Name="txtContent"/>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="brd" Property="Background" Value="#50AAAAAA" />

            </DataTrigger>

        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Depends on how that DataTemplate is actually used. Please try to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try giving a known width somehow to the control showing the DataTemplate. You can use * size in a Grid, or set a Width/MaxWidth.